# React-native-game-engine + matter.js dynamic scale of bodies

Tags: javascript, react-native, matter.js

I'm trying to build a screen with circular bodies (bubbles). The bubbles should be able to change the scale with some interval, e.g. every 3 seconds and random value (from 1 to 3). The scale should change the size of a bubble and its mass.

Calling

> Matter.Body.scale

doesn't make any effect. Bubbles keep staying the same. Maybe because I'm not using sprites with textures, but the Game-Engine entities with renderer as React.PureComponent instead. Not sure

Bubble node:

```
export interface BubbleProps {
  body: Matter.Body;
  item: Item;
}

class BubbleNode extends React.Component<BubbleProps> {
  render() {
    const {body, item} = this.props;
    const x = body.position.x - body.circleRadius;
    const y = body.position.y - body.circleRadius;

    const style: ViewStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: x,
      top: y,
      width: body.circleRadius * 2,
      height: body.circleRadius * 2,
      backgroundColor: item.color,
      borderRadius: body.circleRadius,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      padding: 3,
    };

    return <View style={style}>{item.content}</View>;
  }
}
```

Bubble Entity:

```
const body = Matter.Bodies.circle(
        randomX, 
        randomY, 
        RADIUS, //default radius 25
        {
          mass: 30,
        }
      );

      return {
        body,
        item,
        renderer: BubbleNode,
      };
```

Update method:

```
// find out if the entity was already added to the world
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(entities, id)) {
        //update scale
        const scale = bubble.item.scale
        Matter.Body.scale(bubble.body, scale, scale)
      } else {
        //add new entity
        entities[id] = bubble;
        Matter.World.add(physics.world, [bubble.body]);
      }
```

Also, I need to make this scaling smooth

**Edit:**

Interesting thing. I was able to scale the bubbles using **Matter.Body.scale** but right before adding to the world. I wonder if there is a method to update the bodies after adding to the world.

**Final edit**

this is the method I'm using to set up the world and specify entities for the GameEngine framework

```
private setupWorld = (layout: LayoutRectangle) => {

    const engine = Matter.Engine.create({enableSleeping: false});
    const world = engine.world;
    world.gravity.x = 0;
    world.gravity.y = 0;

    //center gravity body
    Matter.use(MatterAttractors);
    var attractiveBody = Matter.Bodies.circle(
      layout.width / 2,
      layout.height / 2,
      1,
      {
        isSensor: true,
        plugin: {
          attractors: [centerGravity],
        },
      },
    );
    Matter.World.add(world, attractiveBody);

    //walls
    const wallThickness = 5;
    let floor = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
      layout.width / 2,
      layout.height - wallThickness / 2,
      layout.width,
      wallThickness,
      {isStatic: true},
    );
    let ceiling = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
      layout.width / 2,
      wallThickness / 2,
      layout.width,
      wallThickness,
      {isStatic: true},
    );
    let left = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
      wallThickness / 2,
      layout.height / 2,
      wallThickness,
      layout.height,
      {isStatic: true},
    );
    let right = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
      layout.width - wallThickness / 2,
      layout.height / 2,
      wallThickness,
      layout.height,
      {isStatic: true},
    );
    Matter.World.add(world, [floor, ceiling, left, right]);

    //basic entitites
    this.entities = {
      physics: {engine, world},
      floor: {body: floor, color: 'green', renderer: Wall},
      ceiling: {body: ceiling, color: 'green', renderer: Wall},
      left: {body: left, color: 'green', renderer: Wall},
      right: {body: right, color: 'green', renderer: Wall},
    };
  };
```

And here is the method that will be triggered by a parent Component with some interval

```
public updateNodes = (items: Item[]) => {
    if (!this.state.mounted || !this.entities || !this.entities.physics || !this.layout) {
      console.log('Missiing required data');
      
      return;
    }

    const layout = this.layout
    const entities = this.entities

    const bubbles: BubbleEntity[] = items.map((item) => {
      const randomX = randomPositionValue(layout.width);
      const randomY = randomPositionValue(layout.height);
      const body = Matter.Bodies.circle(
        randomX, 
        randomY, 
        RADIUS, {
          mass: 30,
        }
      );

      body.label = item.id

      return {
        body,
        item,
        renderer: BubbleNode,
      };
    });

    const physics = this.entities.physics as PhysicsEntity;
    const allBodies = Matter.Composite.allBodies(physics.world)

    bubbles.forEach((bubble) => {
      //update existing or add new
      const id = `bubble#${bubble.item.id}`;
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(entities, id)) {
        //do physical node update here
        //update scale and mass
        const scale = bubble.item.scale
        console.log('Updating item', id, scale);
        
        //right her there used to be an issue because I used **bubble.body** which was not a correct reference to the world's body.
        //so when I started to use allBodies array to find a proper reference of the body, everything started to work
        let body = allBodies.find(item => item.label === bubble.item.id)

        if (!!body) {
          const scaledRadius = RADIUS*scale
          const current = body.circleRadius || RADIUS

          const scaleValue = scaledRadius/current

          Matter.Body.scale(body, scaleValue, scaleValue)
        }else{
          console.warn('Physycal body not found, while the entity does exist');
        }
      } else {

        console.log('Adding entity to the world');
        entities[id] = bubble;
        Matter.World.add(physics.world, [bubble.body]);
      }
    });

    this.entities = entities
  };
```

In the future, I'm going to improve that code, I will use some variables for the body and will create a matter.js plugin that will allow me to scale the body smoothly and not instant as it works right now. Also, the method above requires some clean, short implementation instead of that garbage I made attempting to make it work

Comment: How are you running the Matter.js engine? I don't think React is terribly relevant here; I'd separate that from a [mcve] that involves stepping the engine forward without the renderer and scaling the bodies, then plug that into React once you have it working in MJS alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example isn't exactly complete; it's not clear how (or if) the MJS engine is running. The first step is to make sure you have an actual rendering loop using calls to [`Matter.Engine.update(engine);`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Engine.html#method_update) in a [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) loop.

React doesn't seem critical here. It shouldn't affect the result since x/y coordinates and radii for each body in the MJS engine are extracted and handed to the View component, so the data flows in one direction. I'll leave it out for the rest of this example but it should be easy to reintroduce once you have the MJS side working to your satisfaction.

The way to scale a body in MJS is to call [`Matter.body.scale(body, scaleX, scaleY)`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_scale). This function recomputes other physical properties such as mass for the body.

There's an [annoying caveat](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/760) with this function: instead of setting an absolute scale as a JS canvas context or CSS transformation might, it sets a *relative* scale. This means each call to this function changes the baseline scaling for future calls. The problem with this is that rounding errors can accumulate and drift can occur. It also makes applying custom tweens difficult.

Workarounds are likely to be dependent on what the actual animation you hope to achieve is (and may not even be necessary), so I'll avoid prescribing anything too specific other than suggesting writing logic relative to the radius as the point of reference to ensure it stays within bounds. Other workarounds can include re-creating and scaling circles per frame.

Another gotcha when working with circles is realizing that [MJS circles are n-sided polygons](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/347), so small circles lose resolution when scaled up. Again, this is use-case dependent, but you may wish to create a [`Bodies.polygon`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Bodies.html#method_polygon) with more sides than would be created by [`Bodies.circle`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Bodies.html#method_circle) if you experience unusual behavior.

That said, here's a minimal, complete example of naive scaling that shows you how you can run an animation loop and call `scale` to adjust it dynamically over time. Consider it a proof of concept and will require adaptation to work for your use case (whatever that may be).

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const circles = [...Array(15)].map((_, i) => {
  const elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("circle");
  document.body.append(elem);
  const body = Matter.Bodies.circle(
    // x, y, radius
    10 * i + 60, 0, Math.random() * 5 + 20
  );
  return {
    elem,
    body,
    offset: i,
    scaleAmt: 0.05,
    speed: 0.25,
  };
});
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
  engine, {element: document.body}
);
const walls = [
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    // x, y, width, height
    innerWidth / 2, 0, innerWidth, 40, {isStatic: true}
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    innerWidth / 2, 180, innerWidth, 40, {isStatic: true}
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    0, innerHeight / 2, 40, innerHeight, {isStatic: true}
  ),
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    300, innerHeight / 2, 40, innerHeight, {isStatic: true}
  ),
];
Matter.Composite.add(
  engine.world, 
  [mouseConstraint, ...walls, ...circles.map(e => e.body)]
);

/* 
naive method to mitigate scaling drift over time.
a better approach would be to scale proportional to radius.
*/
const baseScale = 1.00063;

(function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  circles.forEach(e => {
    const {body, elem} = e;
    const {x, y} = body.position;
    const {circleRadius: radius} = body;
    const scale = baseScale + e.scaleAmt * Math.sin(e.offset);
    Matter.Body.scale(body, scale, scale);
    e.offset += e.speed;
    elem.style.top = `${y - radius / 2}px`;
    elem.style.left = `${x - radius / 2}px`;
    elem.style.width = `${2 * radius}px`;
    elem.style.height = `${2 * radius}px`;
    elem.style.transform = `rotate(${body.angle}rad)`;
  });
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
  background: rgb(23, 0, 36, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg, 
    rgba(23, 0, 36, 1) 0%, 
    rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I actually was able to fix my issue. I used the entities object for the GameEngine to store references to matter bodies, which seems not going to work. In my update method I decided to use Matter.Composite.allBodies(physics.world) to find a required body by label (ID in my case), this way I'm getting a correct reference to the body, that allows me to update it using Matter.Body.scale. I will accept your answer because you were correct about the method and gave a good example to use it

Comment: Nice--if you don't mind writing up an answer, I'd be curious to see how you did it (and you can move the checkmark there if you want).

Comment: Thanks and nice to see you worked it out, although I recommend [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing so you keep the original question and answer distinct and folks can compare answers easier. After adding an answer, you can roll back your edit on the original question.